# Change SQL Structure in a correct Date

Tags: mysql, ddl

[image]

How can I correct the result of a statement if the login script is setting the "created" date 1 month too early. How would you correct the existing data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to set the stored **date** to **date+1 month**?

```
UPDATE `sessions`
SET `sessions`.`created` = DATE_ADD(`sessions`.`created`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Or have I missunderstood your question?

Comment: I want to change the result of the select query

Comment: Then you just have to modify the statement I have written to a select statement:
`SELECT DATE_ADD(sessions.created, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS created FROM sessions`